# Passing multiple value does not work for me

Tags: php, codeigniter

I using codeigniter.I have a form in view page that post the data to a controller class.I dont have much idea about this. Can someone help me code?
My view page:

```
<?php
      //form data
      $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'id' => '');

      $indiatimezone = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata" );
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimezone($indiatimezone);


      //form validation
      echo validation_errors();

      echo form_open('admin/billing/ticket_add', $attributes);
      ?>
  <div id="ticket"> 

<table style=" border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
        <th>Employee</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>ID</th>     
        <th>Mins</th>

        </tr>
        <tr id="1" ondblclick="myid(this)">
        <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo  $date->format( 'H:i' ); ?>"/>

        <td contenteditable="true"><?php  echo form_dropdown('employee', $options_category, set_value('employee'),'style="border-radius:0px; height:15px; font-size:10px; width:70px"');?></td>
        <td  contenteditable="true"><input type="text" name="start_time" value="<?php echo  $date->format( 'H:i' ); ?>"/></td>
        <td  contenteditable="true" ondblclick="mylist()"><input type="text" name="pid" value="<?php echo set_value('pid'); ?>"/></td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="nr"><input type="text" name="mins" value="<?php echo set_value('mins'); ?>"/></td>


        </tr>
        <tr id="2" ondblclick="myid(this)">

            <td contenteditable="true"><?php  echo form_dropdown('employee', $options_category, set_value('employee'),'style="border-radius:0px; height:15px; font-size:10px; width:70px"');?></td>
        <td  contenteditable="true"><input type="text" name="start_time" value="<?php echo  $date->format( 'H:i' ); ?>"/></td>
        <td  contenteditable="true" ondblclick="mylist()"><input type="text" name="pid" value="<?php echo set_value('pid'); ?>"/></td>
        <td contenteditable="true" class="nr"><input type="text" name="mins" value="<?php echo set_value('mins'); ?>"/></td>

        </tr>
</div>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Here I send my data to controller function ticket_add.Below is my tickect_add function in controller.

```
public function ticket_add()
    {
     if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('employee', 'employee');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('start_time', 'start_time');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('pid', 'pid');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('mins', 'mins');


            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>', '</strong></div>');

            //if the form has passed through the validation
            if ($this->form_validation->run())
            {
                $data_to_store = array(
                     'employee' => $this->input->post('employee'),
                    'start_time' => $this->input->post('start_time'),
                    'pid' => $this->input->post('pid'),
                    'mins' => $this->input->post('mins'),


                );
                }
                }
                $this->billing_model->store_bill($data_to_store);
                $data['main_content'] = 'admin/billing/ticket_page';
        $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);

    }
```

Here I get the posted value and send them to model file to store my data. How to do this.Can someone please kindly help me?

Comment: Have a look at the user guide. It has an easy tutorial about creating news items; http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/tutorial/create_news_items.html

Comment: I could post simple form.Please look at my code

Answer (score 0):

are you not doing that already?

```
$this->billing_model->store_bill($data_to_store);
```

this line is passing $data_to_store to function store_bill inside billing_model

Comment: Yes I do. but I have two row in my table that is submitted. No value is inserted. I have 2 rows

Answer (score 0):

You should debug in your model to check for issue...
Considering this as your function in `billing_model`

```
public function store_bill($data_to_store)
{
    $this -> db -> insert( 'your_table_name', $data_to_store );

    // try this 
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    // you will get complete insert query from above line...
    // Execute it in phpmyadmin to check for any error..
}
```